# React Native FlatList onEndReached at the end of the list continues fetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, infinite-scroll

I have a method for fetching data from an api, something like this:

```
   const [data, setData] = useState([]);

   const fetchData = () => {
      const newData = [];
      callApi().then(data => {
         data.forEach(item => newData.push(item)
      }).then(() => {
         setData(newData);
      });
   }
```

I am calling this method every time the end of the list is reached:

```
   <FlatList data={data} onEndReached={fetchData} onEndReachedThreshold={0.15} ... />
```

My problem is that, when the end of the list (the real end, I mean, there is no more data to fetch) is reached this method continues being invoked.

Any ideas how to solve it? I have thought to make a first call to the api to retreive every single item and get the total amount, but I think this will make stupid my other method "fetchData", as in a first moment I will have all items downloaded... But the problem here is that there can be 1M items to retrieve in the api.

Thank you.

Comment: what is ``0.15`` value

Comment: the fetch function will be called when the user has scrolled 1-0.15=0.85 (85%) of the actual viewport